# How to give focus to a button from an EditText?

Tags: android, layout, focus

In my form I have different `EditText` areas and a `Button` on the end.
If I use `android:nextFocusForward` and `android:nextFocusDown` between EditText in my XML file everything is ok, but if I use these in the last EditText in order to give focus to the Button I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{org.test/org.test.myActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException:android.widget.TextView
```

I even tried:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Of course they are in the same GroupView.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if this works, of course this is a code solution not an xml one:

```
button.requestFocus()
```